# How to PROPERLY reinstall Windows 8 on HP 655?

Tags: windows-8

It is creating new temporary user profiles every now and then. I have manually repaired it once, I'm not gonna do the same process all over again. The whole install is generally unstable. I want to have it reset back to factory configuration, i.e. reinstall Windows 8.

It came with a hidden **15 GB "RECOVERY" partition**. But how do I use it? There is also another partition with assigned drive letter containing a single file titled **Recovery**. This partition is about 400 MB. Do I have to double click on this file to start the factory restore?

I had about 25 GB worth of files that I have been working with on **C: drive**. So in order to save that I shrank the **C: partition** and created a new 40 GB partition where I have put those files on.

Are they safe now? Will performing a reinstall of Windows or doing some fancy built-in HP recovery process actually wipe the entire drive?

I have read the manual and I couldn't get it to boot to perform a reinstall of Windows from recovery.

HP support is unreachable, I was told to try calling them later.

I have found an option within Windows 8, called **Advanced Startup**.

`PC Settings>General>Advanced Startup>Troubleshoot>Advanced options>Reset your PC`.

There was an option to restore only the "device" where Windows installed. I chose that one. The other was entire computer or something... don't know.

Will Windows now effectively erase everything on the drive, including my 40 GB backup partition?

They don't exactly use descriptive words in the dialogs like "partition". So I have no idea what to expect will happen... it's been "restoring computer" for 2 hours now, it's at 11% only (just switched to 12%).

It's not fast exactly... should I expect it to complete by the end of the workday? What's it doing anyway?... can I abort?

Comment: The "Reset Your PC" would acomplish what you want.

Comment: And it would not remove my newly created 40 GB partition in the process?

Comment: I read about the F11 key in the manual but I couldn't get it to work. It says to press ESC when prompted to and then F11. Except the said message is not being displayed, only a HP logo comes up.

Comment: What is "Reset Your PC" doing that takes over 2 hours to complete? Any idea? Reminds me of a neverending Windows repair/upgrade process that can take up to 7 hours even on a powerful desktop PC. I mean a clean install of Windows 7 takes 20 to 40 minutes... I think Windows 8 has similar install time, if not better. Is it reading the HP system image (RECOVERY) at all?

Comment: The feature is built into Windows. It will restore your system image. This has nothing to do with the recovery image. It should take awhile, 2 hours does not seem that long, depending on the amount of problems you actually have. The feature only touches the Windows installation, which is well documented, I suggest doing some research.

Comment: So this is actually Windows repairing itself? That would explain why it takes so long. Over 2 hours is not acceptable. Half of my workday was already over, and I couldn't use the computer. So I took the rest of the day off. The weather was beautiful, and spring was in the air. It was much more giving to take a walk and listen to the birds sing, than stare at a monitor and watch Windows "restoring computer" and go from 11% to 12% in like 20 minutes. But I'll have a go at it tomorrow. I just hope it didn't crash or something, because I left it unattended.

Comment: Windows is replacing system files; Yes.

Comment: I think I got confused by the term "reset". I don't know about Microsoft but in my world that means to set it to a previous state, like using System Restore to restore the system to a working state before a major failure occurred, or to have it set back to factory configuration, etc. But if "reset" actually means "repair" then that's pretty messed up.

Comment: Its both the results are the same.  If you do a "Rest" in Windows 8 all data you placed on the computer is lost.  If you do a "Refresh" your personal data is saved but you have to still reinstall your applications.